# Meta data about number of executors and their run time for a Spark application

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to obtain metadata about creation and termination timestamp and how many executors that were launched for a job (i.e., spark application) I run on a spark cluster.

I am not certain that the information I can find in the event-log is correct since it does not correspond to the meta data about the job in the Spark history server Web GUI. For example, the event log shows many more executor IDs than present in the Spark history server Web GUI on the  and the "Executors" tab. In addition, the "Task Time (GC Time)" columns in that tab also show a longer running time of the executors than in the event log.

Is this the creation timestamp of an executor? (Tuesday, December 13, 2022 2:49:24.444 PM)
[image]

Is this the termination timestamp? (Tuesday, December 13, 2022 2:52:04.811 PM)
[image]

Also, the executor ID 10 was not present in the Web GUI. So I am a bit confused here.

So, the questions are: Is it possible to obtain information on when and how many executors that were launched and terminated. If so, where do I find that information? Is it via det REST API?

Comment: Thanks for your question! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Did you try to use this REST API?
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api

Comment: I am looking in the event-log file. I the SparkListenerExecutorAdded, and SparkListenerExecutorRemoved providing the information when the executor was launched and terminated?